# Why doesn't Scala's Either.RightProjection#filter return an Either?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Using Scala 2.9.1, consider the following two instances of `Either`:

```
scala> val er: Either[String, Int] = Right(1)
er: Either[String,Int] = Right(1)

scala> val el: Either[String, Int] = Left("a")
el: Either[String,Int] = Left(a)
```

It's great that, by using the `left` and `right` projections, one can use for-comprehensions (via biased monad of the projected Either):

```
scala> for { r <- er.right } yield r * 2
res6: Product with Either[String,Int] with Serializable = Right(2)

scala> for { r <- el.right } yield r * 2
res7: Product with Either[String,Int] with Serializable = Left(a)
```

Can someone explain to me why the decision was made not to have the `filter` method return an Either? I would have expected the following to work:

```
scala> for { r <- er.right if r > 2 } yield r * 2 // r is NOT greater than 2!
res8: Product with Either[String,Int] with Serializable = Left(a)
```

Instead you get the following error:
    :9: error: value * is not a member of Either[Nothing,Int]
                  for { r <- er.right if r > 2 } yield r * 2

It appears that the underlying call in `Either.RightProjection#filter` actually returns an `Option`:

```
scala> er.right.filter(_ > 2)
res9: Option[Either[Nothing,Int]] = None
```

This defeats the use of the if clause in the for-comprehension, at least the way I was trying to use it.

Does anyone have an explanation of why this design is the way it is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It boils down to the fact that if you have a `Right(b)`, but your filter predicate fails, you have no value to put in a `Left`.

You might imagine an implementation that works for your case of `Either[String, Int]`, by failing with a default value of `Left("")`. The Scala standard library doesn't have the facility to to produce a value for you, because it doesn't include a concept such as a monoid which would determine the "empty" value for a type.

The [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) library does include a monoid typeclass, and version 7 also includes a right-biased disjunction type, `\/[A, B]` (isomorphic to `Either[A, B]`) which has a `filter` method iff the left type is a monoid:

```
scala> \/.right[String, Int](1).filter(_ > 2)
res1: scalaz.\/[String,Int] = -\/()
```

But you couldn't do this for the general case - if you had an `Either[Nothing, Int]`, you could never produce a left value.

Comment: What a great answer, that makes total sense. Does that mean I should do something like: for { r <- er.right.filter(_ > 2).toRight("a").joinRight.right } yield r * 2

Comment: You might prefer a pattern match: `er match { case Right(b) if b > 2 => Right(b * 2); case _ => Left("a") }`